# Just to keep things lively, how about some live debate on the origins of the universe?

Tags: discussion, chat

Personally I think it's a rare question it the field of science and the creation vs. evolution debate that makes a really good fit for this site, but that doesn't mean our community isn't interested in the topic! For anyone with a weather ear out for the subject there is an upcoming live debate* that will be broadcast live online:

> ### Bill Nye Debates Ken Ham
>
> #### Live Streaming FREE on Feb. 4 at 7 PM ET
>
> Is creation a viable model of origins in today’s modern, scientific era? Leading creation apologist and bestselling Christian author Ken Ham is joined at the Creation Museum by popular TV personality and evolution apologist Bill Nye.
>
> Ham, a former science instructor who emigrated to the USA from Australia over 25 years ago, is joined by the popular children’s program personality Bill Nye “the Science Guy” for this first and only scheduled debate. Each man delivers what he believes is the best information currently available for his case. Each then has an opportunity for rebuttal and afterward answers questions submitted by the audience.
>
> http://debatelive.org/

For the purpose, I will make sure the lights are on it the [**Creation vs. ☐**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1254/creationism-vs) chat room. I have also added it as a [chat event that you can register](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1254/creationism-vs?tab=schedule) to get a reminder in chat just before the event starts.

<sub>* I make no promises about the merits of this debate. Ken Ham is a well known name in the field but in my view sometimes harps too much on the weaker possible arguments from the creationist camp. I know nothing about the other player. I present this only as something that (based on the hype I see already) *will be* talked about.</sub>

Comment: So... do you want a reply to this? I think this is just a notification.

Comment: Just a public service announcement. You can use the answer space for whatever you like (within reason). Know of a similar or related event? Want to comment on the merits of this one? Want to recommend resources on the topic that would be useful background to have before chatting? Want to suggest how chat or events like this should be handled instead of how I did it? All these and more in your answer below...

Comment: How will this be handled in the chatroom?

Comment: Business as usual: anybody that shows up can discuss the subject during or after the session. The "event" is just for the reminder system it provides, otherwise just show up in chat. Bring popcorn to share.

Comment: I don't see a real problem because Holy Bible is only an allegorical collection of works that progressively revealed man's search for and understanding of God, anyway.

Comment: One comment rather than an answer: please use a global time standard! I think 7pm ET is 1400h UTC (which actually means I can't watch it, but that doesn't invalidate the request).

Comment: @AndrewLeach You went the wrong way, it's actually 00:00 UTC time (so on the 5th). I only left that here because it is a full quote of the official announcement. If you look at the chat event I created it will figure it out for you automatically in YOUR time zone.